# How to instantiate lists of same type within a complex object ?

Tags: c#, collections

It's a tricky situation I ran into . I know it is a simple one but something i guess I am missing.

There is complex type object ..

```
public class GroupMembershipValidationOutput
{
    public ListGroupMembershipUploadInput GroupMembershipInvalidList { get; set; }
    public ListGroupMembershipUploadInput GroupMembershipValidList { get; set; }

 ...................... // other defs
}
```

The ListGroupMembershipUploadInput looks like

```
public class ListGroupMembershipUploadInput
{
    public List<GroupMembershipUploadInput> GroupMembershipUploadInputList { get; set; }
}
```

Now there is a parent list of objects(that is also of the same type) form where I am parsing the valid and the invalid lists respectively.

```
        GroupMembershipValidationOutput gmvo = new GroupMembershipValidationOutput();

        ListGroupMembershipUploadInput lgl = new ListGroupMembershipUploadInput();

        if (gmvo._invalidChapterCodes.Count != 0 || gmvo._invalidGroupCodes.Count != 0 || gmvo._invalidMasterIds.Count != 0)
        {
            lgl.GroupMembershipUploadInputList = new List<GroupMembershipUploadInput>();
            var result = mainCollection.GroupMembershipUploadInputList
                            .Where(x => gmvo._invalidMasterIds.Select(y => y).Contains(x.cnst_mstr_id) ||
                                        gmvo._invalidChapterCodes.Select(y => y).Contains(x.chpt_cd) || 
                                        gmvo._invalidGroupCodes.Select(y => y).Contains(x.grp_cd)).ToList();

            if (result.Count > 0) //Means there are some invalid items
            {
                lgl.GroupMembershipUploadInputList = result; //Construct the invalid listfrom result
                gmvo.GroupMembershipInvalidList = lgl;

                ......... // How to construct the valid list

            }
```

I tried

```
 gmvo.GroupMembershipValidList = new ListGroupMembershipUploadInput();
```

but it assigns null to the GroupMembershipValidList .. it does not make the count 0.

How to fix it ? Or is it the intended one ?

Comment: Why do you have a `ListGroupMembershipUploadInput` class when you can just use a `List<T>` externally in its place?

Comment: try  `gmvo.GroupMembershipValidList = new ListGroupMembershipUploadInput
            {
                GroupMembershipUploadInputList = new List<GroupMembershipUploadInput>()
            };`